# Python add to MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql, database, web-scraping, storage

Using Scrapy to get some stuff and I want to store it in a Database. Never done anything with MySQL or Python before so looking for some help as to why this wont work.

Here is my code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from metacritic.items import MetacriticItem
from mysql.connector import errorcode
import mysql.connector
import json

class MetacriticPipeline(object):

DB_NAME = 'metacritic'

TABLES = {}
TABLES['titles'] = (
    "CREATE TABLE `titles` ("
    "   `name` varchar (14) NOT NULL,"
    "   PRIMARY KEY (`emp_no`)"
    ")  ENGINE=InnoDB")

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password = 'andy')
cursor = cnx.cursor()

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    if item['title']:
        return item

class JsonWriterPipeline(object):

def __init__(self):
    self.file = open('items.jl', 'wb')

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    line = json.dumps(dict(item)) + "\n"
    self.file.write(line)
    return item

class WriteToDatabasePipeline(object):

def create_database(cursor):
    try:
        cursor.execute(
            "CREATE DATABASE {} DEFAULT CHARACTER SET 'utf8'".format(DB_NAME))
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        print("Failed creating database: {}".format(err))
        exit(1)

try:
    cnx.database = DB_NAME
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
    if err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
        create_database(cursor)
        cnx.database = DB_NAME
    else:
        print(err)
        exit(1)
```

I'm getting this error in CMD when I try run it:

```
File "metacritic\pipelines.py", line 46, in WriteToDatabasePipeline
cnx.database = DB_NAME
NameError: name 'DB_NAME' is not defined
```

Any idea why this is? It looks to me like DB_NAME is defined okay? I just want to make the database for now and try add in tables afterwards.
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining `DB_NAME` inside the `MetacriticPipeline` class, move it at the top of the script (or better move to scrapy settings):

```
from __future__ import print_function
from metacritic.items import MetacriticItem
from mysql.connector import errorcode
import mysql.connector
import json

DB_NAME = 'metacritic'

class MetacriticPipeline(object):
   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

DB_NAME is defined in class MetacriticPipeline, make it global or do this:

```
cnx.database = MetacriticPipeline.DB_NAME
```

Comment: thanks for this. alecxe's answer worked so I will have to accept his but thanks for the reply, I upvoted you anyway :)